# How to troubleshoot PXE boot from DD-WRT dnsmasq not sending tftp server info?

Tags: mac-osx, pxe-boot, dnsmasq, mikrotik, openwrt

I have a **MikroTik hEXs** router (firmware v6.47.1) which I want to flash with OpenWRT.  The OpenWRT wiki site has [detailed instructions](https://openwrt.org/toh/mikrotik/common#netboot_of_openwrt_uses_dhcpbootptftp) on the procedure, and it requires that one netboot the router.  **My problem is that I can't get the hEXs router to reach out to my tftp server for some reason.**

To act as the PXE boot host, I've setup `dnsmasq` on my currently in-use DD-WRT router and set the `dhcp-boot` option in the 'Additional DNSMasq options' text area as follows:

`dchp-boot=initramfs.bin,,192.168.2.108`

I have a `tftpd` instance running on a Mac Mini running OS X Ventura at the IP shown above.  The OpenWRT file I want it to boot is at `/private/tftpboot`.  I've confirmed that tftp works by ftp-ing the file across the network from another machine.

When I power-on the hEXs, and watch `tcpdump` output on the tftp host, I see a ton of requests like this:

```
14:21:36.898688 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
14:21:37.098699 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
14:21:37.298576 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
14:21:37.498588 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
14:21:37.698617 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
14:21:37.898635 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
14:21:38.098664 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from [hEXs MAC ADDRESS], length 300
```

... but I never see anything reaching out to Port 69, where tftpd is listening.  Consequently, I have never been able to get the hEXs to actually boot the firmware.  I have confirmed that the hEXs receives an IP address via DHCP, but it doesn't appear to be retrieving the boot file over tftp (that's my assumption without more fine-grained troubleshooting, which is why I'm asking this question).  I can't seem to find anything relevant in log files, but I may not be looking in all the exhaustive right places.

```
$ cat /tmp/dnsmasq.conf
interface=br0
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.dnsmasq
all-servers
strict-order
domain=attlocal.net
dhcp-leasefile=/tmp/dnsmasq.leases
dhcp-lease-max=102
dhcp-option=lan,3,192.168.2.1
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=lan,192.168.2.100,192.168.2.199,255.255.255.0,1440m
stop-dns-rebind
dhcp-boot=initramfs.bin,,192.168.2.108
```

**How can I low-level troubleshoot `dnsmasq` with the CLI (or something) to determine that it's properly handing out the `dhcp-boot` options to a PXE-boot client?**

*I've scoured the internet for about 2-3 weeks on this, including here on the StackExchange family of sites, and I either haven't used the right terminology, or no one has encountered this specific scenario.*

Comment: Please include your *complete* dnsmasq configuration in the question. Also, ensure you're running with the `log-dhcp` option enabled, and let us know if you're seeing any logs when the microtik is sending requests.

Comment: Adding this, as it *may* be the answer to my question.  I will attempt as soon as convenient.

http://www.aturnofthenut.com/2021/03/17/using-dnsmasq-under-openwrt-as-a-tftp-boot-server/